# Waiting for all tasks to finish using Task Parallel Library in .NET 4.0

Tags: .net, multithreading, task-parallel-library

Is there a shorter way to wait for multiple threads to finish?  Maybe using ContinueWhenAll... but I don't want to run the rest of my code async.

```
List<object> objList = // something

List<Task> taskHandles = new List<Task>();
for(int i = 0; i < objList.Count; i++) {

    taskHandles.Add(Task.Factory.StartNew(() => { Process(objList[i]); }));

}

foreach(Task t in taskHandles) { t.Wait(); }

DoSomeSync1();
..
DoSomeSync2();
..
DoSomeSync3();
..

// I could have used ContinueWhenAll(waitHandles, (antecedent) => { DoSomeSync...; });
// but I'd rather not have to do that.
// It would be nice if I could have just done:

Parallel.ForEach(objList, (obj) => { Process(obj); }).WaitAll();

// or something like that.
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If you replace the `for()` loop with `Parallel.For()` or `Parallel.ForEach()` you don't need a Task list or anything. I'm not sure why you would want a .WaitAll() after a ForEach, doesn't even seem necessary.

The Parallel loops stop when all Tasks are done.

Comment: I want to ensure that all the objects are finished processing before continuing with the DoSomeSync calls.

Comment: @Jeff: Yes I thought so. A Parallel.For() doesn't need a WaitAll.

Comment: I see what you mean now - is there some page that documents this?  I could not find any.

Comment: @Jeff: It's not exactly spelled out, no. But it can be deduced from the description of the aggregate exception and the LoopResult: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.parallelloopresult_members.aspx

Comment: This is not entirely true. Parallel.ForEach returns immediately and the tasks continue to run, whereas using the AsParallel() extension does return after all the tasks complete.